# Uneven LinearLayout weight distribution

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I have a LinearLayout that has four views layed out horizontally. The first and last component are a set size. For the inner two views I want to just share the available space 50:50. I set each to a weight of "1" but when the views are layed out, the views are different sizes depending on the content they hold. 
[image: Screen shot of the layout. The data is hidden but it shows how offset the views are]

Here is my layout xml for reference.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/status" 
        android:src="@drawable/white"
        android:paddingRight="10dip" 
        android:layout_height="35dip" 
        android:layout_width="35dip">
    </ImageView>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/name" 
        android:text="Name" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/status" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:textSize="25dip">
    </TextView>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/description"
        android:text="Description"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/name" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textSize="25dip">
    </TextView>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/time" 
        android:text="Time" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/description" 
        android:textSize="25dip">
    </TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Obviously these aren't the actual column names but I changed them for privacy purposes. This layout is used by a ListView which changes the text of each view to be whatever value its presented. The name and description fields should line up since they're both given 50% of the remaining screen but when the name is longer the description is shifted right. Why?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For the weight to be considered, the layout dimension needs to be 0 (zero)

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/name" 
    android:text="Name" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"  
    android:layout_width="0dip" 
    android:layout_weight="1" 
    android:textSize="25dip">
</TextView>
```

I also recommend making your weight add up to either 1 (and use fractions) or 100.

So instead of 1 you would use either 50 or .5 for each view.  The LinearLayout code will work properly with any weight sum, but it gets difficult if you want to modify your view later with additional sections.

Also, if you are not using relative layout, get rid of the toRightOf attributes.  Less is more.

Comment: I just noticed that while reading through a Google LinearLayout tutorial. Thanks a ton, fixed it

Comment: Technically the width has to all match, not be zero.  If all the widths are set to 0, 200, 9000, or fill_parent as long as they match, weight will be distributed evenly.

Comment: @Eric - The danger there is that the random value you pick for the width may become a new LayoutParams constant in the future.  Think they'll never make LayoutParams.MAGIC_LAYOUT = 9000?  I'm not going to bet on it.  What I want is a LayoutParams.USE_WEIGHT constant.

Comment: @Eric is correct. And this answer is not really correct. As long as all views in the LinearLayout who have weight have the saem width it will be even.

Comment: @Patick using zero width allows for some optimization in layout (avoiding an extra call to measure the child). If you can set your sizes so that the measurement comes out exact, then setting actual widths will help, otherwise there is no need.  So asserting that the size NEEDS to be zero may be overstepping.  I still stand by the answer as I think it is the best thing to do.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `android:layout_width="fill_parent"` instead of "wrap_content" in all children of `LinearLayout`. Or better yet, make such a structure in your xml:

```
<RelativeLayout>
    <ImageView />       # status, fixed width, alignParentLeft="true"
    <TextView />        # time, fixed width, alignParentRight="true"
    <LinearLayout>      # layout_width="fill_parent", toLeftOf="time" toRightOf="status"
        <TextView />    # name, use layout_weight="1"
        <TextView />    # description, use layout_weight="1"
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

This should do what you want. Using `LinearLayout` instead of `RelativeLayout` might work too, but you have to experiment a bit (I believe using nested Layout, as in my example, will do the work).

Comment: I did not try this, but I think fill_parent would have also fixed this issue because I've used it before. +1 for the response, thanks